# Addition and Multiplication in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I was trying to solve a problem in assembly and I manage to write the code but while displaying the results I'm getting a weird output. I was suppose to add the squares of 3 numbers, which one of them is a negative. Here is my code, and this is what I use to assemble, link and run. Thanks!

Compilation and execution steps:

nasm -g -f elf lab1.asm
gcc -o lab1 lab1.o
./lab

```
SECTION .data
message:    db  "Hello, this is Iva.", 0AH
anothermsg  db  "The sum of the numbers %d, %d and %d is %d", 0AH
len:        equ $-message
variable1:  dw  7
variable2:  dw  -11
variable3:  dw  19
SECTION .text
    extern printf
    global main
main:   

mov eax, dword [variable1]
movzx ebx, al
mov eax, ebx

imul eax
push eax



mov eax, dword [variable2]
movzx ebx,al
mov eax,ebx

imul eax
push eax

mov eax, dword [variable3]
movzx ebx,al
mov eax,ebx

imul eax
pop ebx
add eax,ebx
pop ebx
add eax,ebx

push eax

push dword [variable3]
push dword [variable2]
push dword [variable1]
push anothermsg


call printf

mov eax,1
mov ebx,0
int 80h
```

Comment: What is your question? If you're just looking for feedback, you can use http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm not getting the output I'm suppose to, I'm getting totally different numbers

Comment: You might get some answers if you posted the output that you are getting.

Comment: Step through the code line by line and check the values in the registers, in memory, and on the stack. At some point they will not contain the values you expect. That's where the bug is.

Comment: Learn to use the debugger, gdb.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of mistakes.

First, `printf()` accepts ASCIIZ format strings (all C strings are ASCIIZ, IOW, NUL-terminated). Your `anothermsg`, however, does not end with a zero byte. You must append one explicitly.

Second, you declare your integer variables as 16-bit (`dw` = 16 bits), but fetch them from the memory as 32-bit (e.g. `mov eax, dword [variable1]`, `dword` = 32 bits). This may work, but makes little sense. Just declare the integer variables as 32-bit (`dd` = 32 bits).

Third, for reasons unknown to me (perhaps, because of the previous problem), you're truncating 32-bit (or 16-bit, depending on how one interprets it) values to 8 bits with `movzx`, which makes the computation of the square of -11 wrong.

See, you have -11 stored in `variable2` as:

```
1111111111110101 (binary)
```

After these 2 instructions:

```
mov eax, dword [variable2]
movzx ebx,al
```

You get:

```
eax = ????????????????1111111111110101 (??? are the memory contents right after variable2)
ebx = 00000000000000000000000011110101 (245 decimal)
```

Then after these 2 instructions:

```
mov eax,ebx
imul eax
```

You get:

```
eax = 00000000000000001110101001111001 (60025 decimal)
```

If you did `movsx ebx,al` instead of `movzx ebx,al`, you'd get:

```
eax = ????????????????1111111111110101 (??? are the memory contents right after variable2)
ebx = 11111111111111111111111111110101 (-11 decimal)
```

Then after these 2 instructions:

```
mov eax,ebx
imul eax
```

Finally:

```
eax = 00000000000000000000000001111001 (121 decimal)
```